# Scaling photo image on html5 canvas at preset location

Tags: html, canvas, transform, scale

I have been struggling with this problem for sometime, I hope someone would be able to help me out on this.

I have added canvas object in my html code, in which I load a photo image. I am trying to scale the image at some random coordinates, but the scaling happens only from the center of the canvas. If I use translate the whole image moves as the origin changes. I have also tried transform but that too doesn't give the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**use context.drawImage() + extended parameters to scale your original image onto your canvas**

```
context.drawImage(srcImage, srcX, srcY, srcWidth, srcHeight, 
      canvasX, canvasY, scaledWidth, scaledHeight)
```

Where:

- srcImage = your source image
- srcX = the X-coord on your source image you want to start grabbing pixels from
- srcY = the Y-coord on your source image you want to start grabbing pixels from
- srcWidth = width of a rectangle of pixels you want to start grabbing from the source image
- srcHeight = height of a rectangle of pixels you want to start grabbing from the source image
- canvasX - the X coord on the canvas where you want to start painting your pixel rectangle
- canvasY - the Y coord on the canvas where you want to start painting your pixel rectangle
- scaledWidth - scale the *source pixel rectangle* to this width before painting to the canvas
- scaledHeight - scale the *source pixel rectangle* to this height before painting to the canvas

For example:

```
context.drawImage(myMap, 50,50,100,150,  20,20,200,300)
```

This will grab a 100x150px rectangle of pixels from myMap image object starting at coordinate [50,50].

Then it will scale the pixel rectangle to 200x300px.

And finally, it will paint the scaled-up pixel rectangle at coordinate [20,20] on the canvas